# Overlay on vimeo movie on iPad/iPhone not clickable

Tags: iphone, css, ipad, mobile, vimeo

We have a embedded background movie on giardinohotelgroup.ch (if you click on a small movie, the whole movie starts)

On desktop everything works as expected (the topbar is overlapping the movie and the links are still clickable)

The problem is, the same functionality doesn't work on iPad/iPhone.
The links are clickable as long the movie didn't started. As soon the user pushs the playbutton the links are not clickable anymore.

Do someone know why? Should not be a z-index issue because the links are not behind the movie.

Answer (score 3):

iOS does not allow interaction with any elements above a video when the native controls are used, which we do in the current version of our player. On the iPhone, when they hit play it will automatically go into full screen and there is no way to prevent that.